# RESTful API including additional fields

Tags: rest, restful-url

I am designing a RESTful API.

Here is a basic GET API for users resource.

**GET /users**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John doe"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jane doe"
  }
]
```

However, I sometimes need to add additional field to the response. For example, age(not in user table) should be added for some situations.

**GET /users?age=true ???**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John doe",
    "age": 28
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jane doe",
    "age": 24
  }
]
```

Are there any RESTful API guidelines for this case?

Comment: The general HTTP guideline is that if you need 2 different responses to a `GET` request, then either the URL should be different or you should use content-negotation (`Accept*` headers)

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any RESTful API guidelines for this case?

Not really - what you propose is *fine*.

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't place any constraints on (a) what information you include in the representations of your resources or (b) which spelling conventions you use for your identifiers.

You *might* want to consider using an identifier at a higher level of abstraction, rather than trying to enumerate your entire collection of fields in the identifier.

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction. -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)

This often means that you are better off with one resource that lots of different clients can use, rather than trying to support many different smaller "more efficient" resources.

One case where you would want many smaller resources: when the presence/absence of different fields impacts who is allowed to *access* the resource.